# How do I find the workers in my Elixir application?

Tags: elixir, erlang-otp

Working through the [Supervisor and Application](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/mix-otp/supervisor-and-application.html) part of the Getting Started tutorial, I'm writing a unit test for the supervision tree problem at the bottom. I tried starting the top-level supervisor but it failed with this error:

```
  1) test all buckets die if registry dies (KV.SupervisorTest)
     test/kv/supervisor_test.exs:4
     ** (EXIT from #PID<0.111.0>) shutdown: failed to start child: GenEvent
         ** (EXIT) already started: #PID<0.75.0>
```

Apparently the app is already started, so I need to get access to its worker processes. I could use Supervisor.which_children to get them if I had the supervisor. To get that, maybe it would help to have the running `kv` application:

```
iex(28)> kvpid = :application.info[:running][:kv]
#PID<0.77.0>
```

So now I have the PID for the app. Is there some way to get the root supervisor process from this, or do I have to manually register it somewhere to get at it from the test?

Or is there a way to directly get the workers from their names? I tried `:erlang.whereis` but it doesn't find the worker:

```
iex(33)> :erlang.whereis KV.Registry
:undefined
```

I tried using the name of the module directly, but that doesn't work either:

```
test "all buckets die if registry dies" do
    reg = KV.Registry
    KV.Registry.create(reg, "shopping")
    {:ok, shopping_bucket} = KV.Registry.lookup(reg, "shopping")

    Process.exit(reg, :shutdown)
    assert_receive {:exit, "shopping", ^shopping_bucket}
end
```

It fails with this error:

```
1) test all buckets die if registry dies (KV.SupervisorTest)
   test/kv/supervisor_test.exs:4
   ** (ArgumentError) argument error
   stacktrace:
     :erlang.send(KV.Registry, {:"$gen_cast", {:create, "shopping"}})
     (elixir) lib/gen_server.ex:424: GenServer.do_send/2
     test/kv/supervisor_test.exs:6
```

[The code is up on github](https://github.com/ijt/kv/tree/s_o_find_worker_question).

Comment: To get the branch for this question, you have to add this step: `$ git checkout -b s_o_question origin/s_o_find_worker_question`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't find KV.Registry because there's a typo in your code. You call:

```
worker(KV.Registry, [@manager_name, [name: @registry_name]])
```

but the definition is:

```
def start_link(event_manager, buckets_supervisor, opts \\ []) do
```

So you pass [name: KV.Registry] as buckets_supervisor, opts is [] and your worker is therefore not registered under the name KV.Registry.

Try this patch: https://github.com/mprymek/kv/commit/03ce2e4e5ab4287db2fab6de0bb1aeaf0226346f

```
 iex(1)> :erlang.whereis KV.Registry
 #PID<0.111.0>
```

Comment: P.S. if your code correct functioning depends on some argument, it probably should be mandatory. If you defined you function as "def start_link(event_manager, buckets_supervisor, opts)", it would not happen.

Comment: Changing the worker line did it: `worker(KV.Registry, [@manager_name, @bucket_sup_name, [name: @registry_name]])`

Answer (score 6):

If you start the supervisor given it a name, you can get all workers with:

```
Supervisor.which_children(MyApp.Supervisor)
```

What is likely happening is that you are trying to start two `worker(GenEvent, ...)` and they will have duplicated events. Passing the `:id` option explicitly will likely fix it.

Comment: Here's what happens: `iex(1)> Supervisor.which_children(KV.Supervisor)
** (exit) exited in: GenServer.call(KV.Supervisor, :which_children, :infinity)
    ** (EXIT) no process
    (elixir) lib/gen_server.ex:356: GenServer.call/3` even though I can see that the KV.Supervisor has started from a log message. I only have one call to `worker(GenEvent, ...)`.

Comment: Ah, I see. I needed to change the KV.Supervisor.start_link body to `Supervisor.start_link(__MODULE__, :ok, [name: KV.Supervisor])`. Now your snippet works.

Answer (score 1):

After cloning down your repo I looked around. I was unable to start the application. Normally Elixir applications can be started from the command line by running:

```
iex -S mix
```

But when I ran your application I got the following error:

```
** (Mix) Could not start application kv: exited in: KV.start(:normal, [])
** (EXIT) an exception was raised:
    ** (UndefinedFunctionError) undefined function: KV.Supervisor.start_link/0 (module KV.Supervisor is not available)
        KV.Supervisor.start_link()
        (kernel) application_master.erl:272: :application_master.start_it_old/4
```

This means that in `lib/kv.ex` on line 5 your application makes a call to a supervisor named `KV.Supervisor`. I looked at your code and no module has that name, but I see you have module use the supervisor behavior named `KV.Bucket.Supervisor`.

You will need to either define a module named `KV.Supervisor` that implements the supervisor behavior, or update line 5 in `lib/kv.ex` so it calls `KV.Bucket.Supervisor.start_link` instead of `KV.Supervisor.start_link`.

Once you do that you should be able to get all the processes the supervisor is supervising by calling this:

```
Supervisor.which_children(KV.Supervisor) # Pass in the name of your supervisor module
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: KV.Supervisor is defined starting at line 42 here: https://github.com/ijt/kv/blob/s_o_find_worker_question/lib/kv/supervisor.ex. I'm not sure I understand.

Comment: There's one more step when you clone the repo. You also have to check out the branch: git checkout -b s_o_question origin/s_o_find_worker_question.